# Sending in an array to a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to use the same function to check an array of values within a promise chain.

```
/*This works*/
dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(console.log)
.then(dc.checkIfDateIsValid.bind(null,departure_date))
.then(console.log)
.then(rp.bind(null, options))
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);

/*This doesn't work*/
dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(console.log)
.then(Promise.all([dc.checkIfDateIsValid.bind(null,departure_date)])
.then(console.log) // undefined
.then(rp.bind(null, options))
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

How can I accomplish this without having to rewrite the function to take an array?

Comment: Sorry, was missing a open bracket. I'm just simulating an array, in essence I will be passing in an array to chain.

Comment: well, you're correctly passing an array to Promise.all, but the array has only one entry, so i'm not sure what you're trying to accomlish with that.

Comment: Note that the two cases are VERY different. In your first sample, you're passing a function that will return a promise when executed. In the second, you're passing a promise. You should likely instead be passing a function that returns the `Promise.all([....])`

Comment: Ok, so in short I need to rewrite the function. There is no way to do this without rewriting the function, correct?

Comment: you don't have to rewrite anything. What's stopping you from passing an anonymous function to .then?

Comment: I have now tried this, however it returns undefined : 

`dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
  .then(console.log)
  .then(function(){
    for(i in j){
     dc.checkIfDateIsValid(j[i])
    }
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .then(rp.bind(null, options))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);`

Comment: I also tried using bind onto the method but then that seems to break the promise chain.

Comment: As it should. you should be returning a Promise.all([thearray]), but you instead returned nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise.all expects an array of promises. You've done that in your second attempt, but, .then expects a function that returns a promise. Promise.all() evaluates to a promise, not a function that returns a promise, so you'll have to rewrite it like this:

```
.then(function () {
    return Promise.all([dc.checkIfDateIsValid.bind(null,departure_date)]);
})
```